# What data can a web site store if using Facebook for single sign on?

Tags: facebook, single-sign-on

If we use Facebook for single sign on, instead of rolling our own login/registration system, what data are we allowed to keep?

Specifically, are we allowed to store (a) user first name and last and (b) user email address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see the [privacy policy here](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/)